# how to concatenate the output of a print to a string variable?

Tags: python

let's say

```
a="x" # a string
b=1   # a integer
```

how can I run a sudo-code like **c=a+print('{0:.3f}'.format(b))** ?
I want to create a string variable of c with it's value being "x1.000"

Comment: You can just remove the print part. `print` returns None, so there's nothing you can do to add the result *you want* from print. `c = a+"{0:.3f}".format(b)` works fine. But you should probably not mix concatenation with formatting for readability sake. You can say `c = "{}{0:.3f}".format(a, b)`

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica I think it doesn't even return `None`, you just can not assing a `print` to a variable.

Comment: `x = print("hello"); print(x)` --> `None`

Comment: ...I mean, this *can* be done, using `StringIO`, but you aren't showing us a use case that makes it appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just take the string out of the print statement

```
c = a + "{0:.3f}".format(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Print returns none. And there's no need for concatenation. Try:

```
'{0}{1:.3f}'.format(a,b)
```

If you are using a version of python > 3.6, just use f-strings:

```
f'{a}{b:.3f}'
```

result:

```
'x1.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

`print` returns `None` thus what you tried in pseudocode isn't correct as after this is ran what you're adding is `'x'` and `None` which just results in just `'x'`. Although storing `c` then printing it then pre-ppending `a` after would work.

```
a = "x"
b = 1
c = '{0:.3f}'.format(b)
print(c)
c = a + c
```

Comment: Small nitpick: 'sudo code' -> [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion likely arises from the fact that whatever tutorials you've been following have only shown the `.format` function being used to print formatted strings.

But note that `.format` is just a method available on strings. So you can do:

`c = 'This is a {}'.format('string')`